# how to write orderBy query for a attribute with some condition like has relation or not, in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, relation

I want write a query for get all products list with their types. and I like to set order to price.
My models are like this:

```
Product:
    id
    price
    ...

ProductType:
    id
    product_id
    price
    ...
```

Products have price attribute and some products have types (one to many relationship). each type of products have own price. when a product have type, it's price is 0. it means product type's price is important for us.
now when I want to write orderBy to price I don't know how to write query that contains both price I mean when product has type, we query for first type price and when we don't have type, we must query to products own price.
I do all of these in Laravel.

```
Products::with('types')->orderBy(???)->paginate(15);
```

The goal in what I need is that if we want to sort by the cheapest price, first the product is displayed that is either the lowest price or the price of one of the types is the lowest and so on. That is, there may be a situation where a product that has a type is placed between 2 products that do not have a type.

Comment: Try this:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-order-by-relation-column-exampleexample.html

Comment: If a product price = 100 and has two types having price = 50 and 150, which one should be used?

Comment: @Salman A when a product has type, it's price is automatics 0. and when we want to show cheapest products we must show 50 first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use leftJoin to join tables and perform sum of columns and then you can sort it.

```
Product::query()       
        ->leftJoin('product_types', 'products.id', '=', 'product_types.product_id')
        ->select([
            'products.id as product_id',
            'products.name as product_name',
            'products.price as product_price',

            'product_types.id as product_type_id',
            'product_types.name as product_type_name',
            'product_types.price as product_type_price',
            DB::raw('IFNULL((products.price), 0) + IFNULL((product_types.price), 0) as actual_product_prize'),            
        ])
        ->orderBy('actual_product_prize')
        ->get();
```

You can't sort using relations because each product may have different products types with different prize and that you can't use relations to sort it.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me to write a query that I want.

Answer (score 1):

Using sortBy... could help.

```
Products::with('productType')->get()->sortByDesc('productType.price');
```

**or use**

**[edit after comment]**

```
$sortDirection = 'desc';

  Products::with(['productType' => function ($query) use ($sortDirection) {
        $query->orderBy('price', $sortDirection);
    }])->get()->sortByDesc('price');
```

**or model**

It is possible to extend the relation with query functions:

```
 public function productType()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductType')->orderBy('price');
    }
```

**it working for me**

***[Hopefully, this will work]***

```
Product::with(['productType' => function ($query) use ($sortDirection) {
            $query->orderBy('price', $sortDirection);
        }])->get()->sortBy([
             fn ($a, $b) => $a['product_type.price'] <=> $b['price'],
         ]);
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that if there is no type for the product, it must be sorted by the price of the product itself. And that the number of products is too large and the demand for the whole product is not optimal

Comment: That is, there may be a situation where a product that has a type is placed between 2 products that do not have a type. but this query can't get me this answer.

Comment: The ```sortByDesc``` method will only work in the collection. In this case he is trying to paginatie. Which won't work

Comment: @NegarJavadzadeh try new query .

Comment: @Abdul Wadud Somrat Thank you for your help. but I want to sort before get from the database. in your way I will get all the products and after that I will sort. but I don't want to sort all products I want get just 30 of them in price order.

Answer (score 1):

```php
Products::with('productType')
    ->orderBy('price')
    ->orderBy(
          ProductType::select('price')
             ->whereColumn('products.id', '=' , 'product_types.product_id')
     );
```

You can use as a scope and you can pass the order Direction to it so you can use desc and asc, for example

**Product.php**

```php
public function scopeOrderedByProductTypesPrice($query, $order="asc"){

  $query
    ->orderBy('price')
    ->orderBy(
          ProductType::select('price')
             ->whereColumn('products.id', '=' , 'product_types.product_id')
     );
}
```

***use case:***

```php
Products::with('productType')
        ->OrderedByProductTypesPrice('desc')
        ->get()
```

PS: as you may see you can also update the scope and accept the column as an argument the the sorting

Comment: This is not logically correct because when we have a product whose price is between two products that have types, it does not work properly. With this query, we actually put the products that have the type at the beginning or the end of the list and then sort them. But the goal in what I need is that if we want to sort by the cheapest price, first the product is displayed that is either the lowest price or the price of one of the types is the lowest and so on. That is, there may be a situation where a product that has a type is placed between 2 products that do not have a type.